# Understanding Locust WEB UI

Tags: locust

I am new to locust framework. What is RPS shown in web UI (Top right).

[image]

I am trying below 2 use cases :

- use 10 users with hatch rate of 5, i receive 6 as RPS
- use 20 users with hatch rate of 5, i receive 11 as RPS.

As no changes have been made to server side, why is it that the RPS changes as per users. Is it on expected or am i missing something ?

Answer (score 0):

RPS is "Requests Per Second" (AKA throughput)... it's a rate.

In your example, you have doubled the number of users... because you are applying more virtual users, your RPS has increased.